# Can a user be blocked by email address?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Can't provide refs, as the posts are being dealt with as they arrive, but how does admin deal with serial idiots, who just won't take 'go away' for an answer?

Can they be email address banned, IP address? MAC address?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think we require email verification, so that won't work. MAC is local-network. IP could possibly work as a short-term stop-gap, but it's far from perfect (pretty easy to circumvent, could potentially catch innocents in the crossfire).

Comment: ahh, then I guess someone might be in for a day/night of manually filtering 'mr angry' who apparently lost it big time after he got a couple of downvotes on a poor question.

Comment: Flag as offensive if you see them. Enough offensive flags is an auto-delete.

Comment: the last couple of flames have gone within a very short time - but he appears to be setting up new accounts & coming back. I actually find it quite amusing, him venting his ineffectual ire against a community who really doesn't care, but his language is, let's politely call it 'fruity'

Answer (score 2):

- Email address: if he always uses the same and does not post anonymously, this is a possibility.
- IP address: if he does not keep changing it by using proxies/Tor/modem restarting then this is also a possibility, but not a permanent ban, because an innocent user can also be banned if they unforeseenly have the same IP address. But for a ban for a short time, this would work (if he always posts from the same IP).
- MAC address: this address is not sent to the server: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/1119/41002

Comment: his first account was put on a week's hold - he's been back twice I've seen since - it might be a long night for the mods :-(

Comment: I have almost used up all my flags - about 10 times on his clones

Comment: mhm, I need to earn a shed-load more rep before I can do anything other than just flag.

Comment: For Tor, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222394/159624